# plot alphashape3d in plotly or ggplot2 for R

Tags: r, ggplot2, 3d, plotly, mesh

I am trying to take a 3d alphashape and plot it using the plotly or the ggplot2 packages in R. Below is an example using R's native plotting package:

## Torus example

```
library(alphashape3d)
T1 <- rtorus(1000,0.5,2)
T2 <- rtorus(1000,0.5,2,ct=c(2,0,0),rotx=pi/2)
x <- rbind(T1,T2)
```

## Value of alpha

`alpha <- 0.5`

## 3D alpha-shape

`ashape3d.obj<- ashape3d(x,alpha=alpha)`

```
plot(ashape3d.obj)
```

This works well inside of the plot() function, but I cannot seem to get the same look using the plotly or ggplot functions. I know there are ashape3d.obj$triang and ashape3d.obj$tetra properties that are the supposed triangulation points, but when using these as 3d mesh, they do not make the same 3d mesh as plot().

Any help or suggestions for other meshing routines would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. Apparently in the triangulation matrix the points are organized based on where the triangle falls with respect to the shape.

Using the above notation,

```
library(plotly)
ashape3d.obj$triang[,9]
```

holds the organization schema where 0= triangle not in the shape, 1= in the interior, 2= regular, and 3= singular

If you keep the values greater than 0 using

```
temp <- ashape3.obj$triang
temp <- temp[temp[,9]>0,]
```

Then, plot using

```
xx=ashape3d.obj$x[,1]
yy=ashape3d.obj$x[,2]
zz=ashape3d.obj$x[,3]
plot_ly(type='mesh3d',x=xx,y=yy,z=zz,i=temp[,1]-1,j=temp[,2]-1,k=temp[,3]-1)
```

Note that I have subtracted one from the triangulation points due to the index starting at zero, not one.